# Error compiling kernel module linux/module.h: No such file or directory found

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am using a simple example to create a Hello World Kernel module. Link below:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/07/write-linux-kernel-module/

when attempting to run the makefile using "make hello" in the same directory as hello.c. I get the following error:

```
hello.c:1:64: fatal error: linux/module.h: No such file or directory
```

I have successfully installed linux header files with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
$ sudo apt-get install linux-source
```

and I can even navigate to the correct file(s) in  `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-51/include/linux/module.h` but the same error persists.

A similar post on reddit gave me hope but I'm not sure if I am using the proper -I dir syntax in the makefile. 
http://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/2o4u1r/linuxmoduleh_no_such_file_or_directory_found_help/

Any help here would be Greatly appreciated! Thanks!

I am running Xubuntu 14.04 with linux version 3.13.51. kmod installed.

EDIT1: More Info
Here is the makefile:

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: ok! done! It was the same as the tutorial link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, and now I feel so silly...

I was running `$ make` but I was getting an error

> make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

I took this to mean that I wasn't calling make properly so I started calling `$ make hello` to "attempt to make the module" This is where the confusion began as trying to make the file like this was not running the correct make file on my system.

Instead, the real solution was to edit the Makefile to take out the spaces before the build calls and replace them with tabs. This completely fixed my issue and I was able to build without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

I use this Makefile:

```
TARGET = hello
OBJS = hello.o
MDIR = drivers/misc

EXTRA_CFLAGS = -DEXPORT_SYMTAB
CURRENT = $(shell uname -r)
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build
PWD = $(shell pwd)
DEST = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/kernel/$(MDIR)

obj-m      := $(TARGET).o

default:
        make -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

$(TARGET).o: $(OBJS)
        $(LD) $(LD_RFLAG) -r -o $@ $(OBJS)

ifneq (,$(findstring 2.4.,$(CURRENT)))
install:
        su -c "cp -v $(TARGET).o $(DEST) && /sbin/depmod -a"
else
install:
        su -c "cp -v $(TARGET).ko $(DEST) && /sbin/depmod -a"
endif

clean:
        -rm -f *.o *.ko .*.cmd .*.flags *.mod.c

-include $(KDIR)/Rules.make
```

I use it for 3.2 kernels. I think the key is the last line, in which some kernel-dependent rules are added to the Makefile.

```
root@devmachine:~/hello# make
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/root/hello modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64'
Makefile:10: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
  CC [M]  /root/hello/hello.o
/root/hello/hello.c: In function 'init_driver':
/root/hello/hello.c:25:18: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /root/hello/hello.mod.o
  LD [M]  /root/hello/hello.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64'
```

Comment: I just attempted this and I recieved the following error: 'make: Circular hello.o <- hello.o dependency dropped.
ld  -r -o hello.o hello.o
hello.o: file not recognized: File truncated
make: *** [hello.o] Error 1'

Comment: Do you have the `kmod` package installed?

Comment: @meleod_ideafix Yes I just checked and I have kmod installed.